# Looking to generate a regex pattern for matching strings between backslashes

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm looking to create an HL7 (type of message) parser. Part of that is being able to grab hex values which will appear as follows, with xxyy as single-byte hex values, xxyyzz as multi-byte hex values and dd as hex values:

> \Cxxyy\
>
> \Mxxyyzz\
>
> \Xdd…\

I'm having a bit of trouble writing regex that can reliably match these. Can anyone lend a hand?

Edit: The two patterns I have tried thus far which have come close are \\C0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\\. This matches some, but not all, hex values I've tested and \\C.*\\ which matches any value, but doesn't stop at the ending \

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm mostly stuck because I'm not good at regex. So far the closest I've gotten is \\C.*\\. It matches the initial string but doesn't stop at the end backslash. I also tried \\C0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\\ and variations on that. It matches some hex values but not others

Comment: This is a helpful tool for regex i find https://regexr.com/

Comment: Its a cool tool! Unfortunately its only for JavaScript and PHP. There's a checker for Java regex I've been running here https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: You just need to remember to escape the backslashes appropriately (can be \\ or \\\\ depending on where you are doing this- double in Apex) and make sure you don't allow matching the backslash during the (greedy) matching of characters. Your most recent comment example looks about right except for the escaping of the backslash. Backslash is a special character in regex which is why you must escape it.

Comment: Phil I think I am I think (using double backslash) but it looks like stackexchange escaped what I entered. Sorry, I'll try to fix the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remember to escape the backslashes appropriately (can be \\ or \\\\ depending on where you are doing this - double in Apex if I remember right) and make sure you don't allow matching the backslash during the (greedy) matching of characters. Your most recent comment example looks about right except for the escaping of the backslash. Backslash is a special character in regex which is why you must escape it.

Comment: I tried with 2,3 and 4 backslashes. It compiles with 4 (which I'd expect) but doesn't stop at the last \. A test string of "Test \C8BADF00D\ Test \Cxxyy\ Now casting a hex \C0x0f4\ and a fake match Cxxyy and another real \Cxxyy\" matches everything after the first "Test ". I'm not sure what you mean by "make sure you don't allow matching the backslash during the (greedy) matching of characters." but I think that might be my issue

Comment: Phil, the greedy comment was it. I changed to using \\C.*?\\ and that did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Excellent, good to hear.